# vertical and horizontal stretch items with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**stretch items using flex follow this context:**

flex-direction: row; & align-items: stretch; ==> vertical stretch

flex-direction: column; & align-items: stretch; ==> horizontal stretch

**my problem:**
i have direction is row ,but i want vertical and horizontal stretch to appear like columns. symmetrical

```css
.inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
  color: #304FFE;
  border: 1px solid #304FFE;
  padding-block: 5px;
  padding-inline: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-block: 2px;
  margin-inline: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <button>Brightness</button>
  <button>Contrast</button>
  <button>Grayscale</button>
  <button>Saturate</button>
  <button>Sepia</button>
  <button>Invert</button>
</div>
```

**my output:**

[image]

**my purpose:**
[image]

Comment: What you look for is what grid does, not flex ;)

Comment: i know, but is there any way to do it with flex?

Comment: nop, this is typical to grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `flex: 1;` to the `<button>` html element.

[image]

like so:

```css
.inner button {
  flex: 1;
  /* other code */
}
```

> this means if there is some space left, 
> CSS flexbox tries to take all the space it can have.

also `flex: 1` is a shorthand that can be also:

```css
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

---

like he said @G-Cyrillus it can break your code:

so put it inside a `@media` so only mobile versions have this behaviur

---

details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex?retiredLocale=it

Comment: but it breaks if you do not have the same amount of element on each row ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus ok, I edited the answer with your suggestion and name, thank you for the comment :)